# What is the jar file for - "org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.dime.binding.DimeBindingID"

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, attachment

I am trying to use the [JAX-WS DIME Encoder](http://jax-ws-commons.java.net/dime/) to send and receive DIME attachments along with SOAP messages.

However, I am not able to search for the jar file, which is required for `org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.dime.binding.DimeBindingID`.

Can somebody please tell me which jar file should be included in the CLASSPATH to compile the java code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it comes from [JAX-WS commons](http://java.net/projects/jax-ws-commons). The package and class you're looking for are in [their SVN repo](http://java.net/projects/jax-ws-commons/sources/svn/show/trunk/dime/src/main/java/org/jvnet/jax_ws_commons/dime/binding?rev=987). Since it's a java.net project, you'd find the jar in the [java.net maven repo](http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/jvnet/jax-ws-commons/dime/).